# Multivariate time series models for stock market prediction that utilizes the macroeconomics data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, multivariate-analysis, references, algorithms

I wonder what Machine Learning models/library will work best if we want to build a forecasting system of S&P 500 index that is not just based on the daily market data, but also the macroeconomics data like 10-year treasury bond yield, CPI, Fed fund rates, Fed total assets etc.

Suppose we are given the follow data as training data:

(1) Market daily data of S&P 500  **from 1980 to 2016** (open, close etc) and

(2) the data of macroeconomics: 10-year treasury bond yield, CPI, Fed fund rates, Fed total assets etc. **from 1980 to 2021**.

What are some good ML models can we use to forecast data of S&P 500 **from 2016 to 2021** based on the above training data? (Plus, it would be great if there is a tutorial for using these models)

---

As response to the comment below: So far I am only aware of a couple of models that predict the market *with the market data only*. For example: the random forest, xgboost, fbprophet. But I am not aware of any ML algorithm that could take advantage of multiple columns of time series data (which are not independent, i.e. could interact with each other) and predict just one single column.

Comment: What have you learned from your literature review of this topic?

Comment: @Sycorax I added something at the end.